# Ionic Item List - Click on item and change class of others

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

How to manipulate class of item list?
Example:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item"> Item 1</li>
  <li class="item"> Item 2</li>
  <li class="item"> Item 3</li>
  <li class="item"> Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

If I click Item 1 I want to change bg color of all other items. How do I do that?

Comment: Check out [the Angular docs for the `ng-class` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Comment: Hi, I am sorry but I dont get it. Can you explain?

Comment: I added an answer demonstrating the use of `ng-class` in a very simplistic way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simplistic, non-production worthy sample of how you can use `ng-class` to accomplish what you're after. Clicking any of the list items will make the background on the remaining items red. This is accomplished using a local scope variable which is set using `ng-click` and then checking the value of that variable in `ng-class`.

```css
.red {
  background-color: red;
}
.clear {
  background-color: none;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 75px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <ul class="list" ng-init="selectedItem = 0">
    <li class="item" ng-class="{clear: selectedItem === 1, red: selectedItem !== 1 && selectedItem !== 0}" } ng-click="selectedItem = 1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="item" ng-class="{clear: selectedItem === 2, red: selectedItem !== 2 && selectedItem !== 0}" } ng-click="selectedItem = 2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="item" ng-class="{clear: selectedItem === 3, red: selectedItem !== 3 && selectedItem !== 0}" } ng-click="selectedItem = 3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="item" ng-class="{clear: selectedItem === 4, red: selectedItem !== 4 && selectedItem !== 0}" } ng-click="selectedItem = 4">Item 4</li>
  </ul>
```